# Enter key to submit form immediately

Tags: javascript, meteor

**edit**
This question is different than the suggested duplicate in that it uses the `form` element and the event `submit form` where the suggested duplicate does not.

This Meteor client code needs to fire the `submit form` event once Enter key is pressed, but instead it moves the focus to the next input element on the screen till it reaches the last element then it fires the submit, which is not what's needed, rather submit immediately.
How can it be fixed? thx

```
  Template.content.events({
  'submit form': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    concole.log('form submitted');
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="content">
  <form>
    {{#each this.items}} {{> sub}} {{/each}}
  </form>
</template>


<template name="sub">
  {{#if isEqual element "input"}} {{> input}} {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="input">
  <input class={{class}} type="{{#if type}}{{type}}{{else}}text{{/if}}" name={{name}} placeholder={{placeholder}} value={{value}} data-id={{_id}}>
</template>
```

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897058/submit-message-by-pressing-enter

Comment: I do not see any input fields in your code. Are they the `value.[]`? Do you use any external plugins for the form and input elements?

Comment: @Khang edited it. sorry, my bad.

Comment: Does your form contain a button having `submit` type? if not try adding one

Comment: @Khang the form is not suppose to have button of type submit, div is used instead to simulate buttons dynamically created based on data source, styled by bootstrap to dynamically position the "buttons" with correct spacing easily.

Comment: You could still put a button having `submit` type and set style display to `none`, then it does not show on the page and the form can be submitted by enter key

Comment: @Khang I tried this for no avail: `<button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>` still Enter key does not fire the `submit form` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two to solve this problem.

1. 'type="submit"': = You can set type = submit to your all input fields.
2. Call submit method when user press enter key on input fields.

   ```
   Template.content.events = {
      'keypress input': function (evt, template) {
        if (evt.which === 13) {
         $( "form" ).submit();
       }
     },
     'submit form': function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       concole.log('form submitted');
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: is your answer two step solution or one or the other? I tried`keypress input` is not being called when Enter key is hit.

Comment: Can you try to set the event on input template "Template.input.events"?

Comment: keypress did not work, but keydown did on the input template